# How to find centroid of a ellipse in my camshift tracking algorithm?

Tags: opencv, contour, ellipse, centroid

I am tracking user from webcam feed using `opencv` in Python so the code is something like this:

```
cv.EllipseBox( frame, track_box, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, cv.CV_AA, 0 )
```

How do I print out the centroid of this ellipse in code? 
Do I have to convert the image (`frame`) itself to grayscale and use contour centroid to get it? Or can I just use the box `(track_box`) because using contour seems redundant if I already have a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the center is a public data member of RotatedRect (track_box.center)